# AutoMapAttribute and polymorphism

Tags: automapper

**Update 1**

Following the suggestion by Lucian, I removed the attributes from the classes used for the property and added a profile; like this, both tests succeed:

```cs
    public class TargetBaseClass
    {
    }

    public class TargetConcreteClass : TargetBaseClass
    {
    }

    public class TestProfile : Profile
    {
        public TestProfile()
        {
            this.CreateMap<TargetBaseClass, SourceBaseClass>()
                .Include<TargetConcreteClass, SourceConcreteClass>();
            this.CreateMap<TargetConcreteClass, SourceConcreteClass>();
            this.CreateMap<SourceBaseClass, TargetBaseClass>()
                .Include<SourceConcreteClass, TargetConcreteClass>();
            this.CreateMap<SourceConcreteClass, TargetConcreteClass>();
        }
    }
```

The question is: can it be translated to `AutoMap` attribute(s)?
I have several derived classes and I will might add more in the future.
The attribute looked at first sight an easy way to do it.

---

**original question**

I'm having issues using AutoMapper with the AutoMapAttribute.
I created the following test:

```cs
namespace Tests
{
    using AutoMapper;

    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

    using Xunit;

    public class SourceContainerClass
    {
        public SourceBaseClass MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceBaseClass
    { }

    public class SourceConcreteClass : SourceBaseClass
    { }

    [AutoMap(typeof(SourceContainerClass), ReverseMap = true)]
    public class TargetContainerClass
    {
        public TargetBaseClass MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    [AutoMap(typeof(SourceBaseClass), ReverseMap = true, IncludeAllDerived = true)]
    public class TargetBaseClass
    { }

    [AutoMap(typeof(SourceConcreteClass), ReverseMap = true)]
    public class TargetConcreteClass : TargetBaseClass
    { }

    public class AutoMapperTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void TestSourceToTargetMapping()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection().AddAutoMapper(this.GetType().Assembly).BuildServiceProvider();
            var mapper = services.GetRequiredService<IMapper>();
            var source = new SourceContainerClass
            {
                MyProperty = new SourceConcreteClass()
            };
            var target = mapper.Map<TargetContainerClass>(source);
            Assert.IsType<TargetConcreteClass>(target.MyProperty);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestBackwardMapping()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection().AddAutoMapper(this.GetType().Assembly).BuildServiceProvider();
            var mapper = services.GetRequiredService<IMapper>();
            var source = new TargetContainerClass
            {
                MyProperty = new TargetConcreteClass()
            };
            var back = mapper.Map<SourceContainerClass>(source);
            Assert.IsType<SourceConcreteClass>(back.MyProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

With the second test failing:

```
Tests.AutoMapperTests.TestBackwardMapping:
    Outcome: Failed
    Error Message:
    Assert.IsType() Failure
Expected: Tests.SourceConcreteClass
Actual:   Tests.SourceBaseClass
    Stack Trace:
       at Tests.AutoMapperTests.TestBackwardMapping() in /{..}/AutoMapperTests.cs:line 59

Tests.AutoMapperTests.TestSourceToTargetMapping:
    Outcome: Passed

Total tests: 2. Passed: 1. Failed: 1. Skipped: 0
```

Is this mapping not supported or am I missing something?
I'm referencing the package `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 7.0.0`.

Comment: I think you're missing some maps. Drop `IncludeAllDerived` and `Include` explicitly the maps you need.

Comment: @lucian can you provide an example? I tried some combinations but they're not working. Actually, without the `IncludeAllDerived` flag, both tests fail

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: does it mean that it's not possible with only attributes?

Comment: I'm sure it is, but it seems too complicated for attributes.

Comment: You can start by using `IncludeAllDerived` in the working example, but I don't know, what will you do the next time things go wrong? :)